# How to show array elements in List Item Text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, material-ui

I am new to react. I am using ListIemText to show values in the screen. My question is how do I use List Item text to show all the elements of an array in a list.

Here is the code. Kpi_Before is the array element.

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <React.Fragment>
        <AppBar size>Confirm Information</AppBar>
        <br />
        <br />
        <List>
            <ListItemText primary="Title" secondary={Title} />
            <ListItemText
                primary="Details of Best Practice"
                secondary={Details}
            />
            <ListItemText
                primary="What is the Best Practice"
                secondary={What}
            />
            <ListItemText
                primary="Why was the Best Practice Implemented"
                secondary={Why}
            />
            <ListItemText
                primary="How was the Best Practice Implemented"
                secondary={How}
            />
            <ListItemText primary="Implementation Status" secondary={Status} />
            <ListItemText primary="Cost of Implementation" secondary={Cost} />
            <ListItemText
                primary="Benefits of the Best Practice"
                secondary={Benefits}
            />

            <ListItemText
                primary="Time taken for Implementation"
                secondary={Time}
            />

            <ListItemText
                key={idx}
                primary="KPI Before Implementation"
                secondary={Kpi_Before}
            />

            <ListItemText primary="UOM_Before" secondary={UOM_Before} />
            <ListItemText primary="Base_Before" secondary={Base_Before} />
            <ListItemText primary="Base_Before" secondary={Target_Before} />
            <ListItemText primary="Target Date" secondary={dateTime} />
        </List>

    </React.Fragment>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're wanting. You could do something like:

```
<div>
    <ul>{Kpi_Before.map(item => <li key={item}> {item} </li>)}</ul>
</div>
```

This will iterate through the Kpi_Before array. When using .map in React you should have a key for every item so that you need to reference it to remove it using .filter or some other method, React can find it. If for some reason you have equal values in the array you could do something like this instead:

```
<div>
    <ul>{Kpi_Before.map(item => <li key=Date.now()> {item} </li>)}</ul>
</div>
```